# PHP kicks up an SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and SQL, but am creating a login system.  The problem I have hit against is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Surname typed in')' at line 5

So I look into the code, and I believe it refers to:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password, hash, forename, surname) VALUES(
        '". mysql_escape_string($email) ."',
        '". mysql_escape_string($password) ."',
        '". mysql_escape_string($hash) ."',
        '". mysql_escape_string($forename) .",
        '". mysql_escape_string($surname) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

After looking over, I can't see a syntax error.  Anyone spot it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If you print out the resulting SQL your error will be easy to spot

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but on reading the PDO info, I have no idea how to select a table.  This would make it kind hard for me :)

Comment: @Splatter You select a table in PDO the same way you select it in mysql_*.

Comment: `mysql_select_db("logintest")` ? (sorry, I meant db, not table...2am!)

Comment: `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=logintest", "user", "password");` <- how the object is initialized, with the dbname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
'". mysql_escape_string($forename) .",
                                  // ^--- no closing single quote here.
```

You forgot the closing quote mark.